# how to re-create photo gallery on dailylife: javascript, jquery and css

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know of existing javascript libraries to re-create this photo gallery sample found on dailylife.com maybe using jquery and css?

They seemed to have it automate the creation of different sized portrait and landscape photos so it fits nicely in these 4 columns with overall equal heights across the columns. Thanks for any input.

Sample output here: http://www.daylife.com/search?q=valentino+rossi

Comment: Still looking to see if anyone is interested in answering what type of pseudo-code would be involved. I imagine it's calculating available height of each column and setting a height to the last image that is in the set before placing a photo in the next column

Comment: yeah, need to close this out now

Answer (score 1):

you could use http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's a start but there's still the issue of having equal heights on all the columns. That masonry plugin looks like it doesn't take that to account